# Javascript window location object

Tags: javascript

I know somethings i can do with JavaScript location object such as

1. Get the host name of a website
2. The URL of the current page of a website
3. The protocol used in data transfer between a webpage and a web server
4. To navigate from one page to another
5. To obtain the path name of the current webpage

My question is, 
is there anything more i can do with this object?

Comment: everything you can do is clearly listed in the mozilla developer's page [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Comment: Alright @WildWidow i will check the MDN website up

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need about the `window.location` object can be found in the Mozilla documentation which a simple Google search returns:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: On top of this, simply type "location.window" into any popular browsers console and it'll give you all the data attached to the objects.  For instance, on this page I can get [this](http://puu.sh/p9HVx/4c1b973cea.png)

Comment: @PopeyGilbert "location.window" returns "undefined" in the browser(FireFox) console, i tried the other way around, that is "window.location", this returned the full URL of the webpage. Thanks for the image on the link.

Comment: Its `window.location`, he made a mistake

Comment: Alright, but it only returns the full URL of the webpage.

Comment: Yes if you execute it the code will return the full URL but if you add a dot `'.'` after the code: `window.location.` some browsers will show you a list of all the function available to execute on the object.

Comment: A link to docs isn't a valid answer. This is nothing more than a comment